# CoDeSys 2.3 - coils won't activate upon receiving a signal

Tags: codesys

Like I've stated in the title, I have a problem with coils not changing their state. I'm a newbie when it comes to programming PLC, so it's probably something basic. Could someone take a quick look? [coil doesn't react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsQlJ.jpg)

Comment: First thing you can do to check if the coil is the problem, is use something else instead. Try writing the same in Structured Text: ```IF IN0 THEN OUT0 := TRUE; END_IF``` or try using the MOVE box to write TRUE into OUT0. If that also didn't work, then maybe you or something is overriding the OUT0 variable, or %QX0.0 to be exact. Define an arbitrary variable not bound to any output and check if the coil works on it. If it does, then most likely something is overwriting that output. Try other outputs as well (%QX1.0 for example)

Comment: Nothing worked unfortunately :/

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Also, if neither ST, nor MOVE blocks work with normal variables (not bound to IO), then is your code even running? Can it be in STOP mode, or maybe stopped because of an EXCEPTION?

Comment: Are you in simulation mode? If yes note you now only need to go online you also have to start PLC. To see how program works first connect then start,

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Turns out it wasn't in "Run" mode. Like I said, I'm the begginiest begginer. Thanks for the help.